# Processing unnamed and named parameters in a batch-file?

Tags: batch-file, parameters

I need to launch a batch-file with unnamed and named parameters.
The first parameter is always unnamed, all others are named to pass them to an external process within the batch. position and names of the named parameters can be different per each call, but they are always in range %2 to %6 (maximum 5 named parameters).

here is a sample call:

```
batch1.bat "unnamed" "a=1" "b=2" "c=3"
```

inside of the batch I try to grab the first unnamed parameter. then I want to loop over all named parameters and call the external process like this:

```
SET "param1=%1"

:param
if not "%2" == "" (
   SET %2
   SHIFT
   goto :param
)

"something.exe" %param1% -a %a% -b %b% -c %c%
```

but if I call that batch, I get this error:

```
SET "a=1" was unexpected at this time.
```

How can I get this solved?

Comment: I would start by changing ```if not "%2" == "" (``` to ```if not %2 == "" (```, or better, ```if not "%~2" == "" (```. But there's much more wrong with your code, and it would be significantly better for everyone if you submitted genuine argument strings.

Comment: I do not understand why the batch file is called with `"unnamed" "a=1" "b=2" "c=3"` instead of `"unnamed" -a=1 -b=2 -c=3` or `"unnamed" -a 1 -b 2 -c 3` and the batch file passes all arguments except the first one further to the executable `"something.exe"`. Well, even the first argument should be passed unmodified further to the executable. So the batch file can be reduced to `@"something.exe" %*` and that's it. No argument parsing must be done in the batch file itself. PS: `cmd.exe` interprets `=` like `,` and `;` and an OEM encoded no-break space like a normal space on argument parsing.

Comment: @Mofi You are so right! I can just use @"something.exe" %* . Sometimes the answer is so easy!

Answer (score 0):

It is essential that you report the actual error report.

```
c:\106x>shift

c:\106x>SET "a=1"
=1"" was unexpected at this time.

c:\106x>if not ""a=1"" == "" goto :param
```

`c:\106x` is my test directory.

The report says that `=1"" was unexpected`.

This is because `"a=1"` which has become the first parameter after the `shift` was executed. batch then substitutes `"a-1"` for each `%1` found (until another `shift` is executed) so

```
SET %1
```

is executed as

SET "a=1"

which is valid, assigning `1` to `a`

The nest statement is

```
if not "%1" == "" goto :param
```

which is executed as

```
if not ""a=1"" == "" goto :param
```

where a comparison operator (`==` `equ` `neq` `geq` `leq` `gtr` or `lss`) was expected after `""a` but not found.

The cure is to use

```
if not "%~1" == "" goto param
```

where the `~` before the `1` removes enclosing quotes

The colon is not required in a `goto` (except in the special case of `goto :eof` meaning `go to the end of file`)